# How to display only first value of database column in WordPress

Tags: php, wpdb

I have following foreach loop code...

```
<?php

$usernames = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT user_name FROM wpxa_project_members WHERE project_id = 698" );

foreach ( $usernames as $username ) 
{
    echo $username->user_name;
}

?>
```

When I use `echo $username->user_name;` it displays all the usernames from the `user_name` column of database. I want to display only the first username from the list. How to do... Pl help... Thanks...

Comment: using it inside `foreach` will obviously print all usernames

Comment: @Atlas_Gondal... Then plz tell me how to do.. Thanks

Comment: how you want to display them? like in list item or row by row etc

Comment: Actually I want to display in add / remove dynamic input fields...

Comment: can you share the html snippet for displaying them in inside input fields?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the solution... Here it is...

```
<?php

$usernames = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT user_name FROM wpxa_project_members WHERE project_id = 698" );

foreach ( $usernames as $username ) 
{
    $member_username[] = $username->user_name;
}

echo $member_username[0];

?>
```

Hope it may help other users.

Comment: No, no, no... You don't need another array just to access first item... And where's the escaping? And what if there are no users? Your code will cause errors in such case...

Answer (score 1):

```
$usernames = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT user_name FROM wpxa_project_members WHERE project_id = 698 LIMIT 1"
```

Comment: Andrea Somovigo... Actually I want to display all usernames individually... Since `echo $username->user_name;` displays all usernames in one row...

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit hard to guess, what exactly are you trying to achieve, but... Based on your answer, here's much cleaner and more secure code, you can use:

```
global $wpdb;
$usernames = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT user_name FROM {$wpdb->prefix}project_members WHERE project_id = %d",
        698
    )
);

if ( ! empty($usernames) ) {
    echo $usernames[0]->user_name;
} else {
    // there are no users
}
```